Driver Selenium en Whatsapp
Tengo un script en vba que hasta ayer por la mañana funcionaba. El script lo que hacia es usar el driver selenium, para enviar WhatsApp. La mayoría del script funciona, los mensajes de texto los envía perfectamente. Pero al tener que pulsar sobre el botón (+) para adjuntar archivos. No hace el click sobre el botón.
Utilizo:
driver.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[4]/div/footer/div[1]/div/span/div/div[1]/div/button/span").Click
Por lo probado parece que el método Click del Selenium ha dejado de funcionar con WhatsApp, ya que en otras web, funciona correctamente.
Alguien ha tenido el mismo problema y lo ha conseguido solucionar.
Un saludo y gracias.

Solucionado, he tenido que añadir un wait, parece que tarda en cargar.
